# Critical Path Method

Tags: python, django, algorithm, django-views, gantt-chart

I am trying to write a code for finding the critical path. I referred to [this](https://github.com/alfonsodipace/Critical-Path-Method/blob/master/delivery.py) Github code. However this code fails if there are two or more starting tasks i.e. two or more tasks that have 0 dependencies. I cannot think of a way to encounter this. Can someone please help.
This is the example that I tried to execute:[image: Test example]

The code above shows is_Critial=True for all the tasks, whereas it should show False for both the Curtains tasks.

Comment: Just to be clear, I need to be able to differentiate between which starting task is critical and which isnt. Here, the curtains task also has 0 dependencies (terminology according to the code) and the Removing old furniture also has 0 dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify all of the starting tasks to depend on a new, artificial starting task.